# How to use Spring JPA for a custom query when trying to query by date?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a method where I'm trying to find all records based on a date.  I'm using MySQL and the datatype is date. In the database the form is "2019-02-22".

How do I search for a date in this form using the Spring JPA repository?

I've tried to change the format using `SimpleDateFormat` format but then I get errors saying change the datatype to String. I do not want it to be string, I want the datatype to stay date. How is this done?

Here is the repository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT alttransport, customerfull, serviceadv, waitflag, apptdate FROM service WHERE apptdate=:currentDate", nativeQuery=true)
ArrayList<Serviceappt> getCurrentAppt(@Param("currentDate") Date currentDate);
```

Here is the method that gives me error:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Serviceappt> getAppts(Date currentDate) {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    log.info("the date is: "+ dateFormat.format(currentDate));
    ArrayList<Serviceappt> theList = apptRepository.getCurrentAppt(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
    for(Serviceappt appt: theList){
        log.info("the customer is: "+appt.getCustomerfull());
    }
    return theList;
 }
```

The error is:

> The method getCurrentAppt(Date) in the type ServiceapptRepository is
>   not applicable for the arguments (String).

How do I get this to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCurrentAppt` method is waiting for a `Date` parameter, but you are passing `dateFormat.format(currentDate)` which returns a `String`.

`SimpleDateFormat`'s `format` method is used to format a `Date` as `String` according to the specified format.

You don't need to format the date to match your database format, simply pass the date as argument :

```
ArrayList<Serviceappt> theList = apptRepository.getCurrentAppt(currentDate);
```

If you need to display it then you can format it, as you already did :

```
log.info("the date is: "+ dateFormat.format(currentDate));
```